# Titanium Android browser default button bar

Tags: android, titanium

I am creating a web view in Android, Titanium, and want to show button bar having browser default functionality like refresh, open new link etc. It is available in iPhone. But how can i achieve this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

the documentation should provide the answers in more detail, but the simple answer is yes.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.WebView-object